# Peewee: delete with limit

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I have a (very) large table mit >100M rows. I want to delete 1M rows with some condition without running in any table lock or timeout issue.
IMO delete with limit is best choice in this case. 
I'm trying to find a peewee equivalent for a simple sql query

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE condition=1 LIMIT 10
```

My first approach is:

```
Users.delete().where(condition=10).limit(10)
```

but DeleteQuery doesn't have a limit method. oops...

So, what is best practice to delete a huge number of rows with peewee?

Answer (score 4):

If you want delete with limit, then just use a subquery:

```
users_to_delete = User.select().where(...).limit(10)
Users.delete().where(User.id << users_to_delete)
```

Comment: Subqueries! ok, thx. Is there another approach to delete large number of rows in peewee? Except the 2 oblivious: 1 per step with delete_instance and all in one step

Comment: EDIT: subquery wont work in this case because of "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery" :(

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not have support for LIMIT. So NO, is not possible to do this.

Comment: but mysql does support limit with delete http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html . Any way, what is "best practice"?